# Should I use server core vs full install for setting up webserver on a hyper-v VM?

Tags: windows-server-2008, virtualization, installation

I am probably going to use hyper-v running on windows server 2008 standard SP2 for server consolidation. I was thinking that I would do a VM for the web server. I was reading up on just using server core. I am not a big command line fan, but would do it if I had a nice cheat sheet for everything that mattered when setting the server up with IIS, or do I just end up managing those things remotely.

A. Is there a well known cheat sheet for all the command line things I would need to do?
B. Can I manage the core server completely from a remote system, so A doesn’t matter?
C. Any there really any obvious gotchas with a core other than you can’t upgrade after the fact?
D. Any pointers to some good tutorials/blogs on this subject?
E. Should I just stick with Full install or do the Core install?

Comment: All three answers so far have addressed one of my bulleted items, but since the cheat sheet is really important to getting core setup I am giving Tatas the answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are cheat sheets like [this](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/2009.02.geekofalltrades.aspx) yes.  But honestly if you haven't set one up and aren't comforatble with core, I'd wait.  While the benefits are nice, you don't want it to be a hinderance while maintaining it.  I'd definitely get this up and running on a test system and get everything working there first.

Comment: Excellent cheat sheet link!

Answer (score 3):

Please bear in mind that Server 2008 Core does not support asp.net, so if your looking to host .net sites you will need to install the full version, not core. Server 2008 R2 will support asp.net in Core.

Comment: I was confused about that when I was reading the comparisons. Thanks for that tidbit!

Comment: I was all set to use Core for most of my production servers, until I read that little tid-bit.  Make Core seam only useful for DCs, standalone file servers, etc.

Comment: I agree, it was a bit of an odd Idea, glad there putting it back in in r2

Comment: I would have been really upset if I had installed core and gone through all that hassle to find out I couldn't run asp.net. How silly!

Answer (score 0):

With a Core install, there are GUI consoles in the Server 2008 toolkit for remote management of Core servers.

I really would recommend getting familiar with the command line as well though, unless you want to do everything by hand forever. Automation through scripts is an essential skill and familiarity with the command line is essential.

This is a good technet article that shows the official remote management tools for Core, there are also a ton of 3rd party tools as well. http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd184088.aspx

Comment: This will give you a better idea of my situation. 

http://serverfault.com/questions/51762/advice-for-hyper-v-deployment-on-windows-server