# How Many Virtual Servers for a Web Server?

Tags: web, virtualization

I need to run a website (with database) in a virtualized environment, all MS.  There will be one primary server with one available for failover.  We are expecting a pretty managable load, maybe 25 users although the queries may be big.

How would you recommend setting up the virtual servers on the primary physical server?

For example:
-only 1 virtual server running IIS and SQL Server?
-separate IIS and SQL server into 2 virtual servers?
-separate IIS and SQL server and duplicate them, for 4 virtual servers, which isn't necessary for load but might make it easier to upgrade since we could take one off line?
- or something else?

Thanks.

Comment: Why hypervisor? what hardware? what versions of code?

Comment: How long is a piece of string?

Comment: ...and how big is a big query?

Answer (score 1):

I'd suggest separating the Web Server and the Database server since it will be much easier to scale to a separate machine when you need to.

Answer (score 0):

I just worked on this, see my question.

[Advice for Hyper-v deployment on windows server](https://serverfault.com/questions/51762/advice-for-hyper-v-deployment-on-windows-server)

I think reading through that will help you.

IMHO, after playing around with it, I think you should just create 2 virtual servers one for IIS and the other for SQL Server, you can make backups of those VM/VHD and then use those if you need to run tests/upgrade or whatever.